# Inertial frame and isometry

Tags: mathematical-physics, affine-geometry

We call a normed vector space $E$ a *Newtonian space* if $E$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$. With $E$ a Newtonian space, the space $E\times\mathbb R$ is called a *Newtonian spacetime*.

Suppose $E$ is a Newtonian space and $I\subseteq\mathbb R$. A *free particle* in Newtonian spacetime is a map
\begin{align}
p:\ I&\longrightarrow E
\\ s&\longmapsto p(s)=as+b
\end{align}
with some fixed $a,b\in E$. The set
$$W=\big\{(p(s),s)\,|\,s\in I \big\}\subset E\times\mathbb R $$
is called *world line* of the particle $p$.

If a diffeomorphism
\begin{align}
(x,t):\ E\times\mathbb R&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^4
\\ (p,s)&\longmapsto \big(x(p,s),t(p,s)\big)
\end{align}
satisfies $x(W)$ is a straight line, for every free particle, then we say $x$ is an *inertial frame* for the Newtonian spacetime.

I wonder that if $x$ is an inertial frame, and we consider its spatial component
\begin{align}
x:\ E&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^3
\\ p&\longmapsto x(p) = x(p,s)
\end{align}
then would $x$ be a bijective isometry ?

My attempt is to show that $x$ bring a straight line $p(s) = as+b$ of $E$ into a straight line of $\mathbb R^3$, then $x$ should be an affine map. But I have no idea how to show it. Could anyone give me a little help for this problem ? I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question correctly, but consider

$
(p,s)\longmapsto \big(2p,s\big).
$

Then $x$ is an inertial frame but not an isometry.

Comment: oh I think I got your point, that is a nice counter example.

Comment: Please use Markdown for text formatting rather than `$\textit$`. I've made the alterations to your post this time.

Comment: @KReiser thanks, I will keep that in mind